# Custom logging with log4j2 jdbc appender in java

Tags: java, jdbc, log4j2, appender

I am trying to log my events in my database using `log4j2`. Specifically I am using `log4j2 jdbc appender` in my properties configuration file for that purpose. By using default log4j2 log levels everything works. The log values successfully get inserted in database. 
This is my initial appender in my log4j2 properties file:

```
# JDBC appender
appender.db.type = Jdbc
appender.db.name = databaseAppender
appender.db.tableName = db_name.test
appender.db.cf.type = ConnectionFactory
appender.db.cf.class = com.myproject.ConnectionFactory
appender.db.cf.method = getConnection
appender.db.col2.type = Column
appender.db.col2.name = message
appender.db.col2.pattern = %m
appender.db.col3.type = Column
appender.db.col3.name = category
appender.db.col3.pattern = %M{1}
appender.db.col4.type = Column
appender.db.col4.name = timestamp
appender.db.col4.isEventTimestamp = true
appender.db.col5.type = Column
appender.db.col5.name = log_level
appender.db.col5.pattern = %-5p
appender.db.filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
appender.db.filter.threshold.level = info
appender.db.filter.threshold.onMatch = Accept
appender.db.filter.threshold.onMismatch = Deny
```

But then I tried to create a custom log level following this log4j2 site https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customloglevels.html

```
LOG.log(Level.forName("DIAG", 350), "a diagnostic message");
```

It successfully logs the event with the defined log level. And even places the data in database since threshold level is `info` in my jdbc appender. As info intLevel > diag intLevel.

My problem is if I changed the threshold level to `diag` in my jdbc appender it doesn't work at all i.e.

```
appender.db.filter.threshold.level = diag
```

Nothing is inserted in my database. So my first question is why it is not working and please give me any solution if possible.

Another thing is that I twitched around the intLevel of `DIAG` to 10 like:

```
LOG.log(Level.forName("DIAG", 10), "a diagnostic message");
```

And now it is inserting in database but also throws some errors.

```
2019-05-24 12:06:00,248 main WARN Error while converting string [diag] to type [class org.apache.logging.log4j.Level]. Using default value [null]. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown level constant [DIAG].
at org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.valueOf(Level.java:320)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.convert.TypeConverters$LevelConverter.convert(TypeConverters.java:288)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.convert.TypeConverters$LevelConverter.convert(TypeConverters.java:284)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.convert.TypeConverters.convert(TypeConverters.java:419)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.visitors.AbstractPluginVisitor.convert(AbstractPluginVisitor.java:149)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.visitors.PluginAttributeVisitor.visit(PluginAttributeVisitor.java:45)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.generateParameters(PluginBuilder.java:253)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:135)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:964)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:904)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:896)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:896)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:514)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:238)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:250)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:548)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:620)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:637)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:231)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:153)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:581)
at com.myproject.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:35)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not defined intLevel in log4j2.properties file so add

```
customLevel.DIAG =350
```

where 350 is the intLevel.

This may remove the error.